# Subtraction over ranges of bits

Tags: c, optimization, x86, bit-manipulation, x86-64

I have a set of 22 5-bit values (0-31) which are packed together as 110 bits into two 64-bit unsigned integers (i.e. the last 18 bits are always zero).  I want to devise a function which will, for each segment of 5 bits, perform an absolute-value difference.

I am aware of methods of subtraction using bitwise operators on a single number, but here I don't want to worry about overflow between the 5-bit segments.  I am looking for a solution using bitwise operators and/or x86 assembly operations, preferably without any loops.

**EDIT:** To clarify, I will have pairs of these 110 bits which I want to do this difference operation on.  Any suggestions are welcome.

**SOLUTION:** Thanks to @EOF for suggesting the VPSADBW instruction.  I'm going to use 8-bit numbers instead in favor of faster (and more readable) code.

Comment: Can you clarify - what's the absolute-value difference of a single value? (I'm only aware of a difference between *two* values.)

Comment: Also it looks like a "code for me" request.

Comment: I suspect the nastiest part will be the 5-bit number that straddles the two `uint64_t`s.

Comment: @EOF maybe a way to get around that would be to place the 18 free bits towards the end of each `uint64`s instead of being bunched up together.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya: Yes, making it 11 5-bit numbers in one `uint64_t` and using two of those is obviously more sane, and probably more reusable too.

Comment: Show your attempt (some C code), and where it fell short.

Comment: I can divide it 55/55 instead of 64/46 to avoid the straddling.  I'm not sure if there are some shuffling operations which might be useful here.  The real struggle is I'm working with 5 bits instead of 4...

Comment: @EOF I had a very nice scheme in mind but I am running short of 1 exactly 1 bit. I was thinking giving 6 bits to each and using 1 bit for carry. This way before substraction we can set all the carries and subtract. But that will require 66 bits. We have only 64 + 1 (actual carry) = 65 bits.

Comment: The obvious next question is whether using 8-bit numbers instead will *actually* hurt performance in any way, considering that you'll easily find appropriate SIMD instructions for those on many architectures, potentially giving you *a lot* of speedup (AVX2 could do 32 of those at once, AVX512 with the appropriate extension 64, ARM NEON 16...)

Comment: I will have ~41 million of these 110-bit segments and I need to do this operation on every pair.  It seemed wasteful use 8 bit numbers, but really what I want is fast code here.  I'm assuming there's an instruction for the absolute value difference of 2 8-bit numbers?

Comment: If you first do a swap such that the larger segments are in one operand, then do a conventional subtract, it will never overflow.

Comment: @WillCunningham: Well, there's `[V]PSADBW` on x86, which gives you *the sum* of absolute differences between two vectors of `uint8_t`s. I don't think x86 has an instruction for the absolute differences themselves, but ARM NEON does: `VABD`. On x86 you might need two instructions, `[V]PSUBB` and `[V]PABSB`.

Comment: Yes! VPSADBW is what I want.  After the operation I described I need to make sure the sum of all 5-bit numbers is less than 3, and based on the values the data can take this will do it.

Comment: A bit of caution: `VPSADBW` gives you two or four *partial* sums of the absolute differences (one from each run of 8 differences, depending on whether you use the 128-bit form or the 256-bit form), you'll probably need a few extra instructions at the end to get the total.

Comment: Yes, I'll add a horizontal add.

Comment: If you are substracting A from B is it guaranteed that all the 22 sets in A will smaller than those in B? If no, what should be the result? Negative number in 5 bits?

Comment: No, unfortunately not.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `pdep` with a mask like `0b000111111000111111...` to scatter your 5-bit integers into 8-bit fields and use the byte-wise SIMD stuff discussed in the comments above.

Alternately, you could expand them out into 6-bit fields, and with the extra bit set to `1`, and do the subtraction in 64-bit words, but then you'll need to find some [bit-twiddly](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerAbs) way to do the "abs" part in a SWAR fashion. I suspect SIMD would be faster though.

Keep in mind that `pdep` has terrible performance on AMD CPUs: 18 *times* worse throughput!

Answer (score 1):

I think that your best bet may be with the `pdep` (parallel bit deposit) instruction on recent x86 CPUs.  You can use this to quickly expand your 5-bit values into 8-bit values.  Once they are 8-bit values, there are many SSE instructions that you can do.

The following takes a 128-bit value in `rdx:rax` and outputs `xmm1:xmm0` with these split as bytes.

Here is some untested code that I think might work for you:

```
mov r8, abs 0x1F1F1F1F1F1F1F1F

pdep rcx, rax, r8
movq xmm0, rcx

shrd rax, rdx, 16
shr rax, 40 - 16
pdep rax, rax, r8
pinsrq xmm0, rax, 1

shr rdx, 16
pdep rdx, rdx, r8
movq xmm1, rdx
```

The inverse transformation is similar, with `pext` instead of `pdep`.

Comment: Thanks! This will be useful.